# haproxy[4014]: backend has no server available

Tags: backend, haproxy

we need your help to resolve the issue, we are getting 503 error intermittently for our servers.

some of our haproxy configured servers getting 503 error intermittently,we are facing the issues with non production server, haproxy configuration is same for npe and prod, bt we are facing issues with npe, Message from syslogd@localhost at Jun 19 00:56:36 ...
haproxy[4014]: backend XXXXX has no server available!, we tried some many ways to resolve.
can any one help us to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the stderr message start haproxy with -q for quiet mode.

See: https://discourse.haproxy.org/t/backend-has-no-server-available-redirect-to-haproxy-log/3155/5

Otherwise, the message is very real, the health check for the backend server failed, it was removed from the backend pool and there was no other server available. Check your haproxy backend configuration.